# Dafny twostate lemmas and iteration

Tags: heap-memory, dafny

Trying to verify the following code. I got stuck trying to ensure that all entries to the stack are members of the the tree root repr set. Then it became clear that it wasn't clear that the root remained valid after inverting some elements within it. It's unclear to me if my twostate lemma correctly demonstrates that a root node remains valid after a change to an element within it.

```
/**
 * https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/description/
 */
function invertTree(root: TreeNode | null): TreeNode | null {
    if(root == null) return null;
    let queue = [root];
    while(queue.length != 0) {
        let current = queue.pop();
        if(current != null) {
            queue.push(current.left);
            queue.push(current.right);
            //The following in js syntax sugar to swap to variables without a temp variable
            [current.left, current.right] = [current.right, current.left];

        }
        
    }
    return root;
};
```

```
class TreeNode {
    var val: int;
    var left: TreeNode?;
    var right: TreeNode?;
    ghost var repr: set<TreeNode>;

    constructor(val: int, left: TreeNode?, right: TreeNode?)
        requires left != null ==> left.Valid()
        requires right != null ==> right.Valid()
        requires left != null && right != null ==> left.repr !! right.repr
        ensures this.val == val
        ensures this.left == left
        ensures this.right == right
        ensures left != null ==> this !in left.repr
        ensures right != null ==> this !in right.repr
        ensures Valid()
    {
        this.val := val;
        this.left := left;
        this.right := right;
        var leftRepr := if left != null then {left}+left.repr else {};
        var rightRepr := if right != null then {right}+right.repr else {};
        this.repr := {this} + leftRepr + rightRepr;
    }

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, repr
        decreases repr
    {
        this in repr &&
        (this.left != null ==>
        (this.left in repr
        && this !in this.left.repr
        && this.left.repr < repr
        && this.left.Valid()
        ))
        && (this.right != null ==>
        (this.right in repr
        && this !in this.right.repr
        && this.right.repr < repr
        && this.right.Valid())) &&
        (this.left != null && this.right != null ==> this.left.repr !! this.right.repr && this.repr == {this} + this.left.repr + this.right.repr)
        && (this.left != null && this.right == null ==> this.repr == {this} + this.left.repr)
        && (this.right != null && this.left == null ==> this.repr == {this} + this.right.repr)
        && (this.right == null && this.left == null ==> this.repr == {this})
    }
}

method {:verify } invertBinaryTreeIterative(root: TreeNode?) returns (newRoot: TreeNode?)
    modifies if root != null then root.repr else {}
    requires root != null ==> root.Valid()
    ensures root == null ==> newRoot == null
    // ensures root != null ==> newRoot != null && newRoot.repr == old(root.repr) && newRoot.Valid()
    // ensures root != null ==> newRoot == root && newRoot.right == old(root.left) && root.left == old(root.right)
    // ensures root != null ==> forall node :: node in newRoot.repr ==> node.right == old(node.left) && node.left == old(node.right)
{
    if root == null {
        return null;
    }
    assert root != null;
    assert root.Valid();
    var stack: seq<TreeNode> := [root];
    ghost var visited: set<TreeNode> := {};
    ghost var unvisited: set<TreeNode> := root.repr;
    assert TreeUnion(stack) == unvisited;
    assert TreeUnion(stack) == root.repr - visited;
    assert root in root.repr;
    assert root.repr <= root.repr;
    assert root in stack;
    while |stack| > 0 
        modifies root.repr
        invariant root.Valid()
        invariant forall x :: x in stack ==> x in root.repr;
        invariant forall x :: x in stack ==> x.Valid() && x.repr <= root.repr;
        invariant visited + unvisited == root.repr;
        // invariant visited == visited + {stack[0]}
        invariant TreeUnion(stack) == root.repr - visited
        // invariant forall node :: node in visited ==> node.right == old(node.left) && node.left == old(node.right) && node.Valid()
        decreases unvisited
    {
        var current: TreeNode := stack[0];
        assert current in stack;
        ChildNodesAreValid(root, current);
        if current.left != null {
            assert current.left.repr <= root.repr;
            assert current.left in root.repr;
            ChildNodesAreValid(root, current.left);
            stack :=  stack + [current.left];
        }
        if current.right != null {
            assert current.right.repr <= root.repr;
            assert current.right in root.repr;
            ChildNodesAreValid(root, current.right);
            stack := stack + [current.right];
        }
        var temp := current.left;
        current.left := current.right;
        current.right := temp;
        assert temp == old(current.left);
        assert current.left == old(current.right) && current.right == old(current.left);
        ValidSwappingStillValid(root, current);
        visited := visited + {current};
        unvisited := unvisited - {current};
        stack := stack[1..];
    }
    return root;
}

lemma ChildNodesAreInRoot(root: TreeNode, child: TreeNode)
    requires root.Valid()
    requires (root.left != null && child == root.left) || (root.right != null && root.right == child)
    ensures child in root.repr;
{

}

lemma ChildChildrenNodesAreInRoot(root: TreeNode, child: TreeNode)
    requires root.Valid()
    requires (root.left != null && (child == root.left.left || child == root.left.right)) || (root.right != null && (root.right.left == child || root.right.right == child))
    ensures child in root.repr;
{

}

lemma ChildNodesAreValid(root: TreeNode, child: TreeNode)
    requires root.Valid()
    requires child in root.repr;
    decreases root.repr
    ensures child.repr <= root.repr;
    ensures child.Valid()
{
    if child == root {
    }else if child == root.left {

    }else if child == root.right {

    }else if root.left != null && root.right != null {
        assert root.repr == {root} + root.left.repr + root.right.repr;
        if child in root.left.repr {
            ChildNodesAreValid(root.left, child);
        }else if child in root.right.repr {
            ChildNodesAreValid(root.right, child);
        }else{
            assert false;
        }
    }else if root.right != null {

    }else if root.left != null {

    }else{
        assert false;
    }
}

twostate lemma ValidSwappingStillValid(root: TreeNode, child: TreeNode)
    requires root.Valid()
    requires child in root.repr;
    requires child.left == old(child.right) && child.right == old(child.left)
    ensures root.Valid()
{
    ChildNodesAreValid(root,child);
    assert child.Valid();
}

function TreeUnion(nodes: seq<TreeNode>): set<TreeNode>
    reads set x | 0 <= x < |nodes| :: nodes[x]
{
   if |nodes| > 0 then nodes[0].repr + TreeUnion(nodes[1..]) else {}
}
```

Version 2

```
function method PreorderTraversal(root: TreeNode): seq<TreeNode>
    reads root.repr
    requires root.Valid()
    ensures forall x :: x in PreorderTraversal(root) ==> x in root.repr && x.Valid()
    ensures forall x :: x in root.repr ==> x in PreorderTraversal(root)
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| ==> PreorderTraversal(root)[k] in root.repr
{
   if root.left != null && root.right != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.left)+PreorderTraversal(root.right) else if root.left != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.left) else if root.right != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.right) else [root]
}

method {:verify true} invertBinaryTreeIterative2(root: TreeNode?) returns (newRoot: TreeNode?)
    modifies if root != null then root.repr else {}
    requires root != null ==> root.Valid()
    ensures root == null ==> newRoot == null
    // ensures root != null ==> newRoot != null && newRoot.repr == old(root.repr) && newRoot.Valid()
    ensures root != null ==> newRoot == root && newRoot.right == old(root.left) && root.left == old(root.right)
    ensures root != null ==> forall node :: node in newRoot.repr ==> node.right == old(node.left) && node.left == old(node.right)
{
    if root == null {
        return null;
    }

    var nodes := PreorderTraversal(root);
    assert forall k :: 0 <= k < |nodes| ==> nodes[k] in root.repr;
    var i := 0;
    while i < |nodes| 
        modifies root.repr
        invariant 0 <= i <= |nodes|
        invariant root.repr == old(root.repr)
        //invariant root.Valid()
        invariant forall k :: 0<= k < i ==> nodes[k].right == old(nodes[k].left) && nodes[k].left == old(nodes[k].right)
    {
        assert nodes[i] in nodes;
        assert nodes[i] in root.repr;
        var temp := nodes[i].left;
        nodes[i].left := nodes[i].right;
        nodes[i].right := temp;
        ValidSwappingStillValid(root, nodes[i]);
        i := i + 1;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Now in version two it seems to be nearly working but I'm getting one error for the last method invariant about the old(node.left) that `receiver might not be allocated in the state in which its fields are accessed`. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? The style of framing with the recursive Valid() predicate is inherently biased towards recursive tree traversals. To support iterative tree traversals, you are essentially going to need to set up a second version of the Valid() predicate that is non recursive, but quantifies over all descendents, then prove it equivalent to the old Valid predicate, then use the new version to verify your loop.

Comment: Well yes, I suppose that makes sense. I can take that approach.

Comment: Do you know what this new error means?

Comment: I think you need `newRoot.repr == old(root.repr)` somewhere in your postcondition.